# masscan, вывод результатов построчно в файл (без мусора)

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, сеть

Как заставить **masscan** записывать результаты в виде нужных IP в файл, без мусора:

```
IP1
IP2
IP3
IP4
IP5
```

Запускаю так

```
sudo masscan -p3389 --rate 100000 --pfring -iL диапазон1  --output-format list --open-only -oL TEST
```

Вывод такой щас

```
open tcp 3389 68.65.143.138 1452193784
open tcp 3389 8.31.96.146 1452193784
open tcp 3389 107.47.138.99 1452193785
open tcp 3389 107.46.27.70 1452193785
```

Comment: А можно пример с мусором?

Comment: open tcp 3389 68.65.143.138 1452193784

Comment: Поправь вопрос с примером сырого выхлопа.

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1**. Через пайп:

`sudo masscan -p3389 --rate 100000 --pfring -iL диапазон1  --output-format list --open-only -oL TEST | cut -d ' ' -f 4`

**Вариант 2**. Через промежуточный файл:

`sudo masscan -p3389 --rate 100000 --pfring -iL диапазон1  --output-format list --open-only -oL TEST > masscan.dump`

`cat masscan.dump | cut -d ' ' -f 4`

В теории - одно и тоже, но на практике иногда помогает.

Comment: к сожалению вывод не изменился (

Comment: Добавил 2-й вариант.

Comment: Да, спасибо, похоже то что нужно ! Правда не совсем так, а вот как вышло cat TEST  | cut -d ' ' -f 4 >> TEST2 результаирующий файл спарсил в другой

Comment: Ну мой второй варинат выплёвывает на стандартный вывод. Дальше можно поставить ещё 1 пайп или перенаправить в файл.